# Pandas reformatting multiple columns into one.

Tags: python, pandas

I have some code that generates a pandas dataframe of dependencies:

```
Input | Output | Script
```

I am trying to generate a list of distinct values from this matrix as a new table with just one column.

```
nodes
```

I tried

```
Nodes_List = pd.DataFrame({nodes: [dependency['Input'].values,
                                   dependency['Output'].values,
                                   dependency['Script'].values]})
```

but rather than getting all three columns merged I get a three row dataframe with the values as comma separated values inside? How can append the three columns onto each other then get the distinct values elegantly?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say your dataframe is like

```
In [295]: df
Out[295]: 
  Input Output Script
0   aaa    bbb    ggg
1   ddd    hhh    ccc
2   eee    bbb    fff
3   aaa    bbb    kkk
```

You can flatten it using `ravel()` and then take `unique` values

```
In [296]: np.unique(df.values.ravel())
Out[296]: array(['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd', 'eee', 'fff', 'ggg', 'hhh', 'kkk'], dtype=object)
```

Or using `np.unique()` directly on `df` also gives same output

```
In [301]: np.unique(df)
Out[301]: array(['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd', 'eee', 'fff', 'ggg', 'hhh', 'kkk'], dtype=object)
```

And, so can create `Nodes_List` with

```
In [297]: pd.DataFrame({'nodes': np.unique(df)})
Out[297]:
  nodes
0   aaa
1   bbb
2   ccc
3   ddd
4   eee
5   fff
6   ggg
7   hhh
8   kkk
```